# How to add a Google map layer in a pyqgis script

Tags: qgis, python

I'm creating a python plugin for different users that has the layers that each person need to use and work with in QGIS.

I have no trouble adding rasters from Geoserver using the following code:

```
        wmsTicketDSM= QgsRasterLayer('contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:27700&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=Ticket_DSM&password=XXXXXXXXXXXX&styles=&url=http://62.12.41.211:8080/geoserver/exchange_maps/wms&username=admin', 'Ticket_DSM', 'wms')
        if not wmsTicketDSM.isValid():
            print "Layer wmsTicketDSM failed to load!"
        else:
            print "Raster Layer wmsTicketDSM loaded!"
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wmsTicketDSM,False)
```

Now I need to add basemaps. How to add a Google Satellite map on python?